# Startactivity from customPhoneStateListener duplicates activity intent.getextras() NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-activity, phone-state-listener

```
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

    switch (state) {
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
        // when Idle i.e no call
        if (lastCallState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
                || lastCallState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
            lastCallState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
                            CallsMainFragment.first=true;
            Intent intent = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.tabactionbar");
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putString("TAB", "2");
            intent.putExtras(b);
            intent.putExtra("key", "2");
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

        lastCallState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
        lastCallState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
        lastCallState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

That's the CustomPhone State Listener and after a call it's needed to start my activity in com.tabactionbar it's a main activity but

- can't call like `Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContex(),MainActivity.class);` Sincerly i don't know why?
- and if my activity is started it duplicate's that

Any solutions ?

here is how i want to get extras

```
try {
        Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle.isEmpty()){
            Log.e("Bundle", "eMPTY");
        }
        else {
            Log.e("Bundle", bundle.getInt("TAB")+" ... ");
            selectedTab=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("TAB");
            Log.e("Eroor", " don`t contains key");
        }

    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e(e1.getLocalizedMessage()+""+e1.toString(), "Eroor intent");
    }

    try {
        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(selectedTab);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(e.getLocalizedMessage()+"", "Error tab 2");
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

catches NullPointerException because my bundle is empty but why?

Comment: could you specify what `can't call like ...` means? What does `dublicates that` means? Is your activity called/created twice?

Comment: yes it`s created twice

Comment: This means i can`t call : android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Found the solution ... i`m stupid, i`m working with somebody else`s code and MainActivity wasn`t the launcher activity in Manifest file Thanks and sorry :)